# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net

can any one solve this problem am facing 404 Error on Server.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="default.aspx">
      <error redirect="error.aspx" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
```

to redirect user to error page or default page.

Comment: What is the question here? Is a 404 error not redirecting to the `error.aspx` page, but the `default.aspx` page instead?

Comment: The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested.

Comment: If it's not redirecting to the correct page, try using the full path.

Comment: read this article http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/404error.htm

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: It does work for me.  The only part of it that you should need to check is the path.  You cannot use a relative path there.  Is `error404.aspx` in your root folder?  If not, change it but use an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get rid of "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found":

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="0" path="~/404.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
      <!--mode="On"-->
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>   
  </system.web>
```